# form validation code igniter doesn't work

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

i am a beginner in using form validation in codeigniter, now i am trying to use form validation codeigniter library, why this is not executed? i already loaded the `$this->load->library('form_validation');` at the top of my controller. I mean i want the output where it puts error below my input type. Why my error in `array('required' => 'Error Message on rule2 for this field_name'));`  doesnt appear in my view. Only in Response at console

Here is my fullcode:

VIEW:

```
<div class="modal fade large" id="admin_create_acct" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header  btn-success">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h3 class="modal-title">Create Account</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
<form class="form-horizontal" id="frm_create_user">
                <div class="form-group">
              <label for="userFName" class="control-label col-sm-4">First Name:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userFName" id="userFName" placeholder="First name">
                 <div class="msg"></div><!-- form-group -->
              </div><!-- col-sm-6 -->
            </div><!-- form-group -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="userMName" class="control-label col-sm-4">Middle Name:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userMName" id="userMName" placeholder="Middle name">
                <div class="msg"></div><!-- form-group -->
              </div><!-- col-sm-6 -->
            </div><!-- form-group -->
 </form><!-- form-horizontal -->
<button type="button" id="btn_reg" onclick="create_User()" class="btn btn-primary">Create Account</button>
```

i am just trying one input type and some error for validating, now here is my Controller code:

```
public function reg_user(){

       $this->form_validation->set_rules('userFName', 'userFName', 'trim|required',
    array('required' => 'Error Message on First name ')
    );

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userMName', 'userMName', 'trim|required',
    array('required' => 'Error Message on Middle Name')
    );

   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $result['type'] = 'error';
        $result['message'] = validation_errors();
    }else {
       $result['type'] = 'success';
       $result['message'] = 'Whooos..! Your Succes Message';   
    }

    echo json_encode($result);  
}
```

my ajax from view:

```
function create_User() {
   $.ajax({
      url: siteurl+"admin_controls/reg_user",
      type: "POST",
      data: $("#frm_create_user").serialize(),
      dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
          alert(" User Successfully Added added! ");
          $("#frm_create_user")[0].reset();
        }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow this Method.
Or

If you just copy and paste this code it will definately work, all you need to just change the controller name in the form action

```
    public function reg_user(){

         $this->form_validation->set_rules('userFName', 'userFName', 'trim|required',
array('required' => 'Error Message on First name ')
);

          $this->form_validation->set_rules('userMName', 'userMName', 'trim|required',
array('required' => 'Error Message on Middle Name')
);
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

                    $result['status'] = true;
                    $result['message'] = "Data inserted successfully.";

            }else {
                $result['status'] = false;

                $result['message'] = $this->form_validation->error_array();
            }
            echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

**Now the Ajax Part**

In Ajax i am using the FormData function instead of using serialize function. In case if you are going to upload files it will be helpful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form_data").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($("#form_data"));

        $.ajax({
            url : $("#form_data").attr('action'),
            dataType : 'json',
            type : 'POST',
            data : formData,
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            success: function(resp) {
                console.log(resp);
                $('.error').html('');
                if(resp.status == false) {
                  $.each(resp.message,function(i,m){
                      $('.'+i).text(m);
                  });
                 }
            }
        });
    });

    return false;
});
```

**View Part**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href='#admin_create_acct' class="list_sort">Select<a>
<div class="modal fade large" id="admin_create_acct" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog"> 
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header  btn-success">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Create Account</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url('Practice/test_user')?>" method="post" id="form_data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        username : <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="name">
                        <span class="error userFName"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        password : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userMName">
                        <span class="error userMName"></span>
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                </form>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.. Hello sir,, what if i got two input types. i have a problem, because when i made two input types, the two error will output in everyone input type

Comment: So what do you want Tell me exactly. if you have two input fields Then it will show  error messages for each fields.

Comment: is it helpful or not if you are getting any type of problem tell me . Thank You

Comment: it is helpful sir, but in my situation now, it needs something improvement to cater 2 or more input types and provide error in every specific fields

Comment: can i see you controller again i do not understand what you want ?because as in the controller the error will show for each fields with specific  fields  errors.

Comment: i already editted my question sir, please update your answer also.. thank you.

Comment: Hello sir @vishal kumar , i already updated my question with two input types thank you. please reply.

Comment: you've only put the error message below?. can i put it every input message that was error, then below the input type?, i mean every error string will be put below every input type where it is being error in rule? something like 
input type below is error message and next input type and below is error message?

Comment: Check the Updated Answer

Comment: If you have any problem tell me in the chat box

Comment: hello sir, i have a question in chatbox